# Have a colored bar at the top of WP mobile there (Argent) and need to change the color

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am have a site ([www.cehcharlotte.com](http://www.cehcharlotte.com)) that is built on the base of a responsive WP theme (Argent), using a hybrid of CoBlocks and ElementorPro. There now appears a thin cyan bar (<20px ish) immediately above my header space, but this existed prior to enabling the Elementor/ElementorPro plugin.

The bar appears in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) but inspecting the source code is not revealing where the color of the bar is being specified. I don't want the bar gone, I simply want to make it match the page background color.

Any ideas where to locate this color: attribute so that I can set it to the color I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's the border color of the header

This is the selector when you inspect it:

```
.elementor-716 .elementor-element.elementor-element-4c6a73b6 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-color: #02d3c9;
    transition: background 0.3s, border 0.3s, border-radius 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}
```

Just add this and change the color to the one you want.

```
.elementor-716 .elementor-element.elementor-element-4c6a73b6 {
        border-color: #02d3c9;
    }
```